# Purposely Make Script SQL Injectible

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I am in the process of auditing security tools, and I decided a good approach would be to create my own "insecure area" (with randomly generated fake data), so I set up an area that is susceptible to sql injections.  However, I can't actually seem to inject it.  I do notice that when I give it a bad query, the "Here are the accounts found" does not print, but the error messages do not print, either.

Can someone tell me if I am doing something incorrect?

```
<?php

$resultHTML;
if (isset($_POST['email']) || isset($_GET['email'])) {

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password);

    if ($conn) {

        //this part is insecure (intentionally for testing)
        if (isset($_GET['email'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * from badSQL.Two WHERE email = '$_GET[email]'";
        } else {
            $query = "SELECT * from badSQL.Two WHERE email = '$_POST[email]'";
        }

        //echo $query;
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if ($result) {
            $resultHTML = "Here are the accounts found: ";

            $hasAccount = false;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $hasAccount = true;
                $resultHTML .= "<br>".print_r($row);
            }

            if ($hasAccount === false) {
                $resultHTML = "No accounts found.";
            }
        }

    } else {
        $resultHTML = "DB Connection could not be established: ".$conn->connect_error;
    }

}

?>

<html>
<head>

    <title>Two BadSQL Test</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Two Website!</h1>
    <br>
    <h3>Forgot Password</h3>
    <p>Enter your email below, and click submit:</p>
    <form id="forgotForm" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <br>
    <div id="results"><?php echo $resultHTML; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the injection vector you are using? And what data you want to extract from that table?

Comment: What error message are you talking about? If the `Here are the accounts found` is not printed and there's no connection error... then there's no error message to print.

Comment: Try `1' OR '1'='1`. That should be valid SQLi for your above script. Though I'm not sure why you'd want to *deliberately* make your own site more vulnerable, as creating a vulnerability for encapsulated fake data could serve as a vector for legitimate attacks.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that last one worked!  It turns out I was using bad queries (probably mismatched single quotes).  Also, as a note, I've already removed all sensitive data from the entire site before doing this (in other places as well).

Comment: ^ Awesome; will write as an answer :)

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, in what way can this be leveraged for a real attack (assuming I have actual sensitive data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1' OR '1'='1` should be valid SQLi for your above script, as it would evaluate to:

```
"SELECT * from badSQL.Two WHERE email = '1' OR '1'='1'"
```

It doesn't matter that the email address will always be wrong, as it makes use of an `OR` clause. Considering `1` will **always** equal `1`, the expression as a whole will always hold true. Thus, the above script will 'skip over' all of the email checks, and then attempt to find the first user to satisfy the condition of `'1' = '1'`. This correlates to the first user in the table (which is usually an administrator as the ID would be 1, leading to further exploitation).

To prevent against this, I'd recommend making use of [**stored procedures or parameterised queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), and making the first user in each table have the fewest privileges possible. I'd also recommend checking out the **[OWASP SQLi Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)**.

An equivalent non-vulnerable PHP parameterised query would look something like:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM badSQL.TwoWHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Do something with $row
}
```

Also, I'd recommend against deliberately making your own site more vulnerable, as creating a vulnerability for encapsulated fake data could serve as a vector for legitimate attacks.

Hope this helps :)